# Why not possible to upload a file to wamp server from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios7, wamp, wampserver

My iPhone application uploads a file to a wamp server over Wi-Fi.

How can I upload the file through the Cellular Data Network(3G,4G)?

Comment: should be exactly the same...unless the the uri is localhost:// in which case you need to figure out what the ip address of your system is, open the appropriate ports, etc.

Comment: It is, so you are doing something wrong. Show some code. Describe your WampServer setup...